# How to convert a list of turple relationship to dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I trying to convert an DataFrame of relationship to a Pandas DataFrame using an column value as column name. For example, convert this:

```
      measure docid  result
   0      P_5   100  0.2000
   1     P_10   100  0.2000
   2     P_15   100  0.1333
   3     P_20   100  0.1000
   4     P_30   100  0.0667
   5    P_100   100  0.0200
   6    P_200   100  0.0100
   7    P_500   100  0.0040
   8   P_1000   100  0.0020
   9      P_5  1000  0.2000
   10    P_10  1000  0.1000
   11    P_15  1000  0.1333
   12    P_20  1000  0.1500
   13    P_30  1000  0.1000
   14   P_100  1000  0.0300
   15   P_200  1000  0.0150
   16   P_500  1000  0.0060
   17  P_1000  1000  0.0030
   18     P_5  1001  0.2000
   19    P_10  1001  0.3000
```

to this:

```
   docid    P_5   P_10   P_15   P_20   P_30  P_100  P_200  P_500 P_1000
   100   0.2000 0.2000 0.1333 0.1000 0.0667 0.0200 0.0100 0.0040 0.0020
   1000  0.2000 0.1000 0.1333 0.1500 0.1000 0.0300 0.0150 0.0060 0.0030
   ...
```

Comment: I think the best is first try `pivot` or `unstack` and if it failed use `groupby` + aggregate function or slowier `pivot_table`. The slowiest is `crosstab`

Comment: Yes, I try find more.

Comment: thank u, guys... I was having trouble finding the right terms to search.